# saving bold/underlined strings to doc file on windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

i want to save some bold / underlined text into a word document in wp8 and then later allow users to upload it to onedrive and use the whole document on pc or open on the phone with office.

i can write simple strings into the document with this code

```
private void Mentes(string adat)
    {

        try
        {
            using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            using (var stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(filename + ".doc",
                System.IO.FileMode.Create,
                System.IO.FileAccess.Write,
                store))
            {

                StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
                writer.Write(adat + Environment.NewLine);
                writer.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Nem sikerült elmenteni" + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

How can i make these strings show bold/ underlined in my documents?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `FontWeight` and `Inlines` property. Try this snippet:

```
TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
tb.Inlines.Add("Sample text with ");
tb.Inlines.Add(new Run("bold") { FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold });
tb.Inlines.Add(", ");
tb.Inlines.Add(new Run("italic ") { FontStyle = FontStyles.Italic });
tb.Inlines.Add("and ");
tb.Inlines.Add(new Run("underlined") { TextDecorations = TextDecorations.Underline });
tb.Inlines.Add("words.");
```

For reference you could read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/cc189010(v=vs.105).aspx).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes that would work in a textbox, but i want my word document to show the saved string in bold/italic/underlined form.

streamwriter writes it in a simple string format